# How do I npm install for current directory and also subdirectories with package.json files?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a an application which is a web game server and say for example I have node_modules which I use in directory ./ and I have a proper package.json for those. it happens that in directory ./public/ I have a website being served which itself uses node_modules and also has a proper package.json for itself.

I know I can do this by navigating the directories. But is there a command or way to automate this so that it is easier for other developers to bootstrap the application in their system?

Comment: you mean something like this https://www.exratione.com/2015/01/run-npm-install-on-all-subdirectories-containing-packages/ ?

Comment: I saw that and thought it was kind of intimidating. All of what I am using is cross platform so a developer in any type of OS can install this thing I am doing. I do not know a thing about BASH, is this the only way to do this? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 22):

Assuming you are on Linux/OSX, you could try something like this:

`find ./apps/* -maxdepth 1 -name package.json -execdir npm install \;`

Arguments:

**./apps/*** - the path to search. I would advise being very specific here to avoid it picking up package.json files in other *node_modules* directories (see maxdepth below).

**-maxdepth 1** - Only traverse a depth of 1 (i.e. the current directory - don't go into subdirectories) in the search path

**-name package.json** - the filename to match in the search

**-execdir npm install \;** - for each result in the search, run *npm install* in the directory that holds the file (in this case *package.json*). Note that the backslash escaping the semicolon has to be escaped itself in the JSON file.

Put this in the postinstall hook in your root *package.json* and it will run everytime you do an *npm install*:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "find ./apps/* -name package.json -maxdepth 1 -execdir npm install \\;"
}
```

Comment: I am getting error as `Illegal escape sequence` at `\;`

Comment: @Pratik try `"postinstall": "find ./apps/* -name package.json -maxdepth 1 -execdir npm install \\;"`

Comment: This doesn't find the `package.json` at the root, as the OP requested

Comment: Just update the search path if you want the root `package.json` included (you may want to increase the maxdepth to compensate).

`find . -maxdepth 3 -name package.json -execdir npm install \;`

Answer (score 1):

For cross-platform support (incl. Windows) you may try my solution.
Pure Node.js

Run it as a "preinstall" npm script

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const child_process = require('child_process')

const root = process.cwd()
npm_install_recursive(root)

function npm_install_recursive(folder)
{
    const has_package_json = fs.existsSync(path.join(folder, 'package.json'))

    if (!has_package_json && path.basename(folder) !== 'code')
    {
        return
    }

    // Since this script is intended to be run as a "preinstall" command,
    // skip the root folder, because it will be `npm install`ed in the end.
    if (has_package_json)
    {
        if (folder === root)
        {
            console.log('===================================================================')
            console.log(`Performing "npm install" inside root folder`)
            console.log('===================================================================')
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('===================================================================')
            console.log(`Performing "npm install" inside ${folder === root ? 'root folder' : './' + path.relative(root, folder)}`)
            console.log('===================================================================')
        }

        npm_install(folder)
    }

    for (let subfolder of subfolders(folder))
    {
        npm_install_recursive(subfolder)
    }
}

function npm_install(where)
{
    child_process.execSync('npm install', { cwd: where, env: process.env, stdio: 'inherit' })
}

function subfolders(folder)
{
    return fs.readdirSync(folder)
        .filter(subfolder => fs.statSync(path.join(folder, subfolder)).isDirectory())
        .filter(subfolder => subfolder !== 'node_modules' && subfolder[0] !== '.')
        .map(subfolder => path.join(folder, subfolder))
}
```

Comment: This one did not work. It became infinite loop